# Mongoose id function returning null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get a sub-document from MongoDB. I can get the parent document, which looks like:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5550a7948be994430f7df1b4"),
        "address" : "Grafton St, Dublin 2",
        "coords" : [
            -6.2597468,
            53.3422998
        ],
        "facilities" : [
            "food",
            "irish history"
        ],
        "name" : "Laura Dunphy",
        "openingTimes" : [
            {
                "days" : "Monday - Friday",
                "times" : [
                    "10am",
                    "12pm",
                    "2pm"
                ]
            },
            {
                "days" : "Saturday",
                "times" : [
                    "8am",
                    "10am",
                    "12pm"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "rating" : 3,
        "reviews" : [
            {
                "author" : "Simon Holmes",
                "id" : ObjectId("5550c26e8c334adebc7c5dc3"),
                "rating" : 5,
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2013-07-15T23:00:00Z"),
                "reviewText" : "Great guide, it was fun."
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I do:

```
console.log('guide.reviews is ');
console.log(guide.reviews);
```

I see:

```
guide.reviews is 
 [{ id: 5550c26e8c334adebc7c5dc3,
  rating: 5,
  timestamp: Tue Jul 16 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (IST),
  reviewText: 'Great guide, it was fun.',
  createdOn: Fri May 15 2015 18:20:57 GMT+0100 (IST),
  author: 'Simon Holmes' }]
```

Which is fine. But then when I try to get the review using the Mongoose id function, I always get back null:

```
review = guide.reviews.id('5550c26e8c334adebc7c5dc3');

console.log('review is ');
console.log(review);
```

With result:

```
review is
null
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've never used this method, but, the docs say it searches for a matching *"_id"*, all i see in your sub document is `id`

Comment: @KevinB You are right, the subdocument got saved with an id rather than a _id. When I change to _id, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`MongooseDocumentArray.id(id)`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_documentarray_MongooseDocumentArray.id) method searches the document array for an `_id` property, but your subdocuments don't have an `_id` property, they instead have `id`. You'll either have to change it to `_id`, or use a plain old `.filter()` or similar workaround.

Comment: This also works with parent.subdocument.id(id) method in the mongoose module also!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I've never seen that sort of API in Mongoose before.

[`document.id`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-id) exists, but it's a function that returns the stringified version of the `_id` field.

In your case, you can just go through the list with a loop and select the one you want.

```
var review = false
for (var i = 0; i < guide.reviews.length; i++) {
    var el = guide.reviews[i]
    if(review._id == '5550c26e8c334adebc7c5dc3') {
        review = el
    }
}
```

If you use lodash, you can also use the [`indexBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy) method to convert the array to an hash in which all items are identified by the specified field:

```
var _ = require('lodash')
var reviews = _.indexBy(guide.reviews, '_id')
// Then you can do reviews['5550c26e8c334adebc7c5dc3']
```